# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{-n^2}x^n$ does not converge for $x=\pm e$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Show that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{-n^2}x^n$$ does not converge for $x=\pm e$. Mathematica says that $$a_n:=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{-n^2}e^n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}e^\frac{3}{2}$$ so $a_n$ does not converge to $0$ which means that $\sum a_n$ does not converge as well as $\sum (-1)^na_n$. But how does mathematica obtain this result? I failed to show that. Also I can't show that $a_n$ is strictly increasing (which would also suffice). I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
a_n = \exp\left[n -n^2 \log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right]
= \exp\left[n -n^2\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{2n^2} + o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)\right] \sim e^{3/2}.
$$